# Pararphrasing question

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, context, paraphrasing

I have come across the following the sentence : (I ripped my shirt on a nail )

Can I just say " The nail ripped my shirt " instead .

Comment: //I ripped my shirt on a nail.// It sounds like one consciously did it. Else, it can be "My shirt was ripped by a nail; My shirt got ripped on a nail", etc. It is not wrong to say, "The nail ripped my shirt" but it needs to be linked to a context like, "When I was repairing my bike, the (a) nail ripped my shirt."

Comment: Yes -----------

Comment: @GRam pillai Thank you , totally agree

Comment: @Ram Pillar I'm happy that "I['ve] ripped/tore/torn my shirt on a nail." is perfectly idiomatic (at least in most of the UK) and would not be taken to imply a deliberate act sans context demanding that interpretation. I'd even say it's the most common way of saying this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth :)

Answer (score 3):

As a sentence standing alone, it would imply that the nail had attacked your shirt on its own.

You could use it as part of a longer narrative. *There was a nail sticking out of the fence. When he pushed me, I fell against the fence and the nail ripped my shirt.*

Comment: Thank you for the useful explanation.

Comment: +1 "The nail ripped my shirt" smacks of blame-shifting in a way; in the end the effect is the same, but who- or what-ever **actively** does the verb is naturally seen as the perpetrator.